how to properly configure timestamp format column with athena table
Here is a rip-off table configuration I am working on in Athena. the data is in a bucket as json gzip files.
The column is timestsamp with the format yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss
CREATE external TABLE json_tab(
  `timestamp`            timestamp
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true'
)
LOCATION 's3://bucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'json.max.read.errors' = '100',
    'compression.type' = 'GZIP' ,
    'timestamp.formats' = 'yyyyMMdd\'T\'HH:mm:ss,yyyyMMdd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS,yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss'
);

querying the table I get HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error Parsing a column in the table: Cannot create timestamp, parsing error.
if I set the column as string and then select with parse_datetime("timestamp",'yyyyMMdd''T''HH:mm:ss') it works. but that means I am converting on select which consumes more resources and time.
Tried different table conf with no luck.

Try using Hive JSON SerDe (docs), it allows to specify "timestamp.formats" in the SERDEPROPERTIES (also use "  so you don't need to play with escaping)

no luck, same error

Initially, as you can see in the question I set ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'. However, when I changed it to  ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe" the issue went away.

You have wrote "no luck" to my comment but your answer claims that what my comment have suggested works (i.e. switching to Hive JSON SerDe).

Nir, can you please clear up the confusion that @GuruStron points out? Thanks
